# Como colocar link usando o RazorPage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, view, razor-pages

Estava estudando um pouco mais sobre o MVC e travei em uma questão que aparentemente deve ser simples, porém já quebrei a cabeça e não consegui fazer com que funcione de jeito nenhum!

Criei um projeto asp.net core 5.0 e agora está utilizando **Razor Pages**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu criei minha **Controller** via Scaffolding ele automaticamente criou uma pasta chamada **Views** ( que é onde eu terei as views das minhas respectivas controllers )

Eu estou com dificuldade em criar um link da minha Index.cshtml que me leve para a Index de fornecedores

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está referencia que coloquei no **asp-page** não está funcionando.

Seria algo que eu tenha que configurar na minha class Startup?

Essa aqui é a parte da classe Startup

```
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MeuBanco>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddScoped<MeuBanco>();
            services.AddScoped<IProdutoRepository, ProdutoRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IFornecedorRepository, FornecedorRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IEnderecoRepository, EnderecoRepository>();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

Eu esqueci de algo? Ou todas as minhas views teriam que estar dentro dessa pasta **Pages**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom primeiro você esta confundindo um pouco as coisas, bem provável que no momento da criação do seu projeto você deve ter selecionado a opção **ASP.NET Core Web Application** ao invés da **Aplicativo Web ASP.NET Core (Model-View-Controller)** pois as aplicações são diferentes!

Do modo que você está querendo realizar, com essa questão do redirecionamento para uma outra **View** é necessário a criação no modo de **Model-View-Controller**

Esse modo que você criou, não tem a necessidade de ter uma pasta **Controller**, onde há as requisições, pois toda requisição da sua View estará na própria **PageModel**

Para entender um pouco mais, sugiro você ler a documentação onde explicação qual escolher e a diferença de cada uma. Tem também um tutorial, ajudaria bastante para entender todo o processo de criação de cada aplicação!

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-BR/aspnet/core/tutorials/choose-web-ui?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 2):

Eu vejo duas possíveis soluções para esse teu problema

- Uma é usar a tag helper **asp-controller** apontando para o nome da sua Controller.

Ficaria desta forma:

```
asp-controller="Fornecedores" asp-action="Index"
```

- Ou usar a tag helper **asp-area** apontando para a pasta raiz das views.

Ficaria assim:

```
asp-area="Fornecedores" asp-page="/Index"
```

Na documentação do ASP.NET tem um artigo sobre Anchor Tag Helpers

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0